# Phpunit exclude tests from execution based on TestCase

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have a nested structure of test cases like this:

`ControllersTestCase -> ControllerTest`

`ControllersTestCase -> WidgetTestCase -> WidgetTest`

`OtherTestCase -> OtherTest`

When I run tests I want to exclude all tests that extend `ControllersTestCase`.

I've tried to add @group annotation to the `ControllersTestCase` like this

```
/**
 * @group controllers
 */
class ControllerTestCase extends \Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
```

For this case I want all Widget tests to be excluded as well.

When I run `phpunit --exclude-group controllers` tests are still executed.

I have many tests under `ControllerTestCase` so it is the last option to visit all of them and add `@group` to each of them.

So what can I do to exclude all tests that inherit from `ControllersTestCase`?

Answer (score 1):

### A bit on PHPDoc inheritance for classes

> Perhaps the simplest of all elements, because a DocBlock for a class makes full use of the object-oriented principles that PHP offers and inherits the following information from the superclass (unless overridden):
>
> > *Summary*
> >
> > *Description*
> >
> > The following tags:
> >
> > *author
> >     copyright
> >     package
> >     subpackage
> >     version*

### Excluding tests with PHPUnit

Three ways to do this:

- Use that `@group` PHPDoc tags (but that's a lot of work)
- Use `<exclude>` tags in `phpunit.xml` and specify the paths to exclude there
- Use `martTestAsSkipped` call inside `setUp` method of the class you want to start skipping tests from. All the child classes will inherit it. (This is probably your bet here, though using `xml` configuration file is more clean and agile. The latter may be a pain though, with specifying those paths)

Comment: Thanks for the response. At the end I've created tests suit where I've included/excluded files I needed. Luckily they were more or less in the same folder.